# customize action url in account confirmation mail

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutterflow

I have created the account confirmation mail in firebase auth .THe link succesfully confirms the account creation,but the confirmation page to sign that appears is not quiet appealing how Can I replace it with page I created[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOrc6.png)